# sending email when cell meets criteria in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone help me modify this script so it will send an email to anyone who has "Send Email" in row 6 at present it sends to everyone, been on this problem for a week, 
Thanks in advance from a none programmer

```
 function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 4; // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2]; // Third column
    var emailSent = row[6]; // Seventh column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nV0VGwbyNiGcQAqmgTVSpdUB_NIISsrFkou0nyw8QQo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share the outcome of your current script. If I read your code correctly it should sent an email for every row that doesn't have `EMAIL_SENT` in column `G`. Which would be everyone at the moment. Your if statement should probably be something like `if (emailSent == "Send Email") {`

Comment: Thanks for your response Casper, it fills in column 2(C) with email send once one is sent, but I am trying to get it to send if "Send Email" is in column 6(G) which is the sum of cells(E&F), so that would mean rows 3&4

Comment: Try the if statement I've provided you in my previous comment instead of the statement you're using in your code right now. Also, if this does not work, please update your question both with the outcome of your initial script + the outcome of the modification with the other if statement.

Comment: Have you tried to change it? What happened with your attempt? Did the documentation not explain how the methods your script uses work, and the parameters they expect to receive?

Comment: It worked with the if statement you provided after I moved the formula from row 6 to row 2, Thanks a bunch

Comment: seems issue solved, problem was only with conditional statement. cheers